# How to enforce one method in WCF Rest to be called via https, while others can be called over http

Tags: wcf, wcf-rest

Is there a way in a WCF Rest Service implementation to require one method be called over https, while allowing others to be called over http or https without having to define two service endpoint bindings?  I want to be able to do something in my service implementation such as:

```
if (CalledOverHttps()) {
   //Do Stuff
} else {
   throw new WebOperationException("Nice try buddy");
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I handled this with IIS, and requiring https on a virtual directory. So in my directory structure i have:

non secured:
http://foo.com/someservice.svc

secured:
https://foo.com/secure/someservice.svc

and if you tried
http://foo.com/secure/someservice.svc, an appropriate 500 error is thrown by IIS.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure, but I believe you can configure it in the bindings.

I have to look it up, though.